# Directory's in HTML/CSS - I.e. Home -> SomePlace -> SomePlace2 ->SomePlace3

Tags: html, css, redirect, directory, hyperlink

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve in means of HTML code. I quickly wrote this up to give an example.

```
<body>
   <div id="directory_container">
     <a class="directory" href="/home">Home </a>/
     <a class="directory" href="/home/marketplace">Marketplace </a>/
     <a class="directory" href="/home/marketplace/major_products">Major Products</a>
   </div>
</body>
```

A good example is a file directory let's say you're in the C:/ Drive and then navigate your way to the following directory.

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

As you can the see the computer understands where you are currently and the previous file url's you had to visit in order to get to this directory. I have the ability to click on any of those 5 locations and instantly relocate to that directory.

This is what I would like on my website, but I feel that manually doing this with the above example can prove tedious and unmanageable if the website is to grow and really increase with 500+ pages and that's a minor value. Which is why I'm asking if there is some automated way to provide this feature so I won't have to go through this if for some reason the URL's on the website change or the path files change etc.. I'm starting to believe this doesn't readily exist, but I could be wrong and is why I'm asking this.

I'm willing to do PHP, but would prefer only HTML/CSS which I'm going to assume is impossible since you would need the information from the server regardless. I also would like to stay away from JavaScript / Plugins.

I hope I've worded this better if there are any other concerns on what I'm requesting I can supply more information and possibly examples. A good example is GitHub and how you have an online navigation of your file storage. I basically want the same for a website only instead of it working exactly how the windows folders work. I want it to be more like each URL is linked to a given Name and I can perform a navigation based off that if possible.

Here's are much better examples of a website that uses the idea I'm wanting. So as you can see I'm looking at a better means of making this work instead of manually doing it all.

http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Medium_Quests
https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/git_remote_helpers/git

You'll see that they both supply these navigation menus I'll try finding more if my question still isn't understandable.

Comment: Can you use PHP on your webserver?

Comment: Yes I can and if this is the only way to achieve it then I'm willing to perform that, but from what I could find researching it. There seemed to be problems with getting current working directory and I wasn't able to find much on creating a path of directories. Which is leading me to believe the option doesn't exist. Which would be nice to find out exactly what my options are for this setup which is why I asked this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I'll add my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I apologize I guess I asked this question a little poorly should have maybe put more thought in to it.

Basically in some websites you'll see almost like a navigation directory if that's a good choice of words. Like Home -> Marketplace -> ProductA -> Etc..

This what I want, but my dilemma is that let's say the website becomes large and changes are made. I'll need to manually rewrite all of these a tags to support that or possibly use some software. Both of which seem uneeded which why I'm asking if there are alternatives.

The bar would merely be a way to navigate backwards is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you'd like to add a menu to all your pages and would like to easily be able to change this menu without updating 500+ files.

You can achieve this by using a PHP include. First create a file in your root directory and name it `menu.html` (you can use the PHP extension as well if you like) all the other files should be named like: `index.php` (PHP extension since we'll be using PHP in the other files)

In the `menu.html` file just build your menu like you want and in all the other files you should include the menu like this:

```
<?php include('/menu.html'); ?>
```

This will get the menu file and output it in the document where you place that tiny piece of code.

**Tip:** Most websites don't only have a recurring menu on each page but rather a recurring header and footer, maybe you could make files for those rather than for the menu. :)

Good luck! If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

---

**Edit**

What you are looking for are "Breadcrumb tails" so the user can easily go back to the previous directory. Unfortunately there isn't any HTML/CSS way to do this automatically for all your pages. With JavaScript and PHP however there are many ways to do this, google for "Automatic Breadcrumbs PHP" or "Automatic Breadcrumbs JavaScript".

This little script will give you a head start:

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $currentpage = ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",(basename($page,".php"))));
    $currentdir = ucwords(basename(dirname($page)));
    $topdir = basename(dirname(dirname($page)));
?>
<div id=nav">
    <ul><li><a href="/" id=home">Bandersnatch Cutlery</a>
            <ul><li><a href="/<?php echo $topdir; ?>"><?php echo ucwords($topdir); ?></a>
                <ul><li><a href="../"><?php echo $currentdir; ?></a>
                     <ul><li><a href="#"><?php echo $currentpage; ?></a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li></ul>
            </li></ul>
    </li></ul>
</div>
```

Source: http://demosthenes.info/blog/220/Breadcrumb-navigation-with-PHP (Edited the indents)

Comment: Some of that information is actually quite useful for another concern of mine which I wasn't going to really make a topic about, but I've edited the main post with a more simplified version of the problem and multiple examples of usage or were it may be used.